# Call controller method from button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, view, controller

I want to call this method in the controller

```
  def setplaylist
   @stream.programmed_at = Time.now.to_i
  end
```

With this line from the view

```
<%= button_to 'Reprogram', @stream, :method => :setplaylist, :remote => true %>
```

I get a No routes match [POST] error.

**Edit:**
My routes.rb file

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'splashpage/splash'
  root :to => 'splashpage#splash', :as =>'splash'


resources :streams do
  resources :videos

end
```

**EDIT 2** rake routes

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
splashpage_splash GET    /splashpage/splash(.:format)                  splashpage#splash
           splash GET    /                                             splashpage#splash
    stream_videos GET    /streams/:stream_id/videos(.:format)          videos#index {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  POST   /streams/:stream_id/videos(.:format)          videos#create {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
 new_stream_video GET    /streams/:stream_id/videos/new(.:format)      videos#new {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
edit_stream_video GET    /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id/edit(.:format) videos#edit {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
     stream_video GET    /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#show {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  PATCH  /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#update {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  PUT    /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#update {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  DELETE /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#destroy {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
          streams GET    /streams(.:format)                            streams#index {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  POST   /streams(.:format)                            streams#create {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
       new_stream GET    /streams/new(.:format)                        streams#new {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
      edit_stream GET    /streams/:id/edit(.:format)                   streams#edit {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
           stream GET    /streams/:id(.:format)                        streams#show {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  PATCH  /streams/:id(.:format)                        streams#update {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  PUT    /streams/:id(.:format)                        streams#update {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  DELETE /streams/:id(.:format)                        streams#destroy {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
```

rake routes | grep setplaylist

```
       stream_videos GET    /streams/:stream_id/videos(.:format)          videos#index {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  POST   /streams/:stream_id/videos(.:format)          videos#create {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
 new_stream_video GET    /streams/:stream_id/videos/new(.:format)      videos#new {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
edit_stream_video GET    /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id/edit(.:format) videos#edit {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
     stream_video GET    /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#show {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  PATCH  /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#update {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  PUT    /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#update {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  DELETE /streams/:stream_id/videos/:id(.:format)      videos#destroy {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
          streams GET    /streams(.:format)                            streams#index {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  POST   /streams(.:format)                            streams#create {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
       new_stream GET    /streams/new(.:format)                        streams#new {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
      edit_stream GET    /streams/:id/edit(.:format)                   streams#edit {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
           stream GET    /streams/:id(.:format)                        streams#show {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  PATCH  /streams/:id(.:format)                        streams#update {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  PUT    /streams/:id(.:format)                        streams#update {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
                  DELETE /streams/:id(.:format)                        streams#destroy {:member=>{:setplaylist=>:post}}
```

I am receiving a no method error after making Max's changes. undefined method setplaylist_stream_path.

Comment: Post your `routes.rb` code

Comment: Try like this `<%= button_to 'Reprogram', :controller =>'your_controller_name',:action => 'setplaylist' :method => :get, :remote => true %>`

Comment: Oops i missed a comma(,) it should be like this `<%= button_to 'Reprogram', :controller =>'your_controller_name',:action => 'setplaylist',:method => :get, :remote => true %>`

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"setplaylist", :controller=>"streams_controller", :id=>"teststream", :method=>:post, :remote=>true}. I am using friendlyids so the id is a string not a integer

Comment: Can you post your `rake routes output`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the setplaylist route.  In your routes file, change this

```
resources :streams do
  resources :videos
end
```

to

```
resources :streams, :member => {:setplaylist => :post} do
  resources :videos
end
```

Now your button_to (which generates a post request by default, i think) should work.  it's better to change the syntax to this:

```
<%= button_to 'Reprogram', setplaylist_stream_path(@stream), :remote => true %>
```

You'll also need to make sure that @stream is defined when your action code runs.  You also probably want to save @stream after you've changed it.  Change your action to

```
def setplaylist
  @stream = Stream.find(params[:id])
  @stream.programmed_at = Time.now.to_i
  @stream.save
end
```

If this is all that it does, i would actually just do this in a call to the usual 'update' action rather than make a new action for it.

Comment: Im getting NoMethodError in Streams#edit. undefined method `setplaylist_stream_path'

Comment: Can you do, in the terminal, `rake routes | grep setplaylist`